# Select Option With jquery-select2

Tags: php, jquery-select2

I am using `jquery-select2` for multiple option select.

I have a form where user can add two options from `select2` select field and it is get inserted in to mysql as comma separated value. **It is working ok.**

Now **if user want to edit it**, with following code in `edit_work.php`, he is seeing each tag value twice in select option.

I have two mysql databases..... one is `research_tag` and second is `research_work`.
During first upload user get tag values from `research_tag` and it get inserted into `research_work` table.

Coding I have tried in `edit_work.php` is :

```
<div>Tags :<br><font style="font-size:12px;">Select Tags Or Keywords For Your Research Work</font></div>
<div class="form-field-input">
<?
$tags = $workdataedit['tags']; // retrives values added by user during first upload
$tagarray = explode(',', $tags);

$tagsquery = mysql_query("select * from reseach_tags order by tags ASC");
?>

<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple" name="tags[]" id="tags[]" required>
<? 
while ($tagdata = mysql_fetch_array($tagsquery)){ 
    foreach ($tagarray as $item){?>

    <option value="<?=$tagdata['tags']?>" <?if ($item == $tagdata['tags']){?> selected="selected"<?}?>><?=$tagdata['tags']?></option>
     <?}}?>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2({

  maximumSelectionLength: 2
});
</script>
</div>
```

How to get option values Only Once in Dropdown ?

**Image :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you can make your query more efficient by only selecting what you actually want from each row. You only seem to use the `tags` column.

Then to remove the duplications use `distinct` like this

Also if you use the newer `foreach (): .... endforeach;` and `while (): .... endwhile;` code format it will be easier to read your code when you eventually come back to amend it.

Although I cannot see a reason for the `foreach` loop inside the `while` loop so this can probably be removed.

```
<div>Tags :<br><font style="font-size:12px;">Select Tags Or Keywords For Your Research Work</font></div>
<div class="form-field-input">

<?php
    // retrives values added by user during first upload
    $tags = $workdataedit['tags']; 
    $tagarray = explode(',', $tags);

    $tagsquery = mysql_query("select DISTINCT tags 
                              from reseach_tags 
                              order by tags ASC");
?>

<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple" name="tags[]" id="tags[]" required>

<?php
    while ($tagdata = mysql_fetch_array($tagsquery)) :
        // This inner foreach appears to be redundant  
        //foreach ($tagarray as $item) :
?>

<option value="<?=$tagdata['tags']?>" <?if ($item == $tagdata['tags']){?> selected="selected"<?}?>><?=$tagdata['tags']?></option>
<?php
        // redundant loop removed
        //endforeach;
    endwhile;
?>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2({

  maximumSelectionLength: 2
});
</script>
</div>
```

> Please dont use [the `mysql_` database extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), it
>   is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7) Specially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` database extensions.
>   [Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) its really pretty easy